How to force Intel Fortran to include MKL code into and EXE (mklsequential.2.dll not available)
How do I get Visual Studio 2019 configured with Intel Fortran 2023 to link the MKL linrary code into an EXE that is generated by building a Fortran project? A few MKL routines have been used in this project. The project runs in Debug and Release modes (inside VS) but the .exe does nor run in a cmd shell, because it does not have the mklsequential.2.dll needed. I need help building such .exe with Visual Studio. If not inside VS, then I need simple instructions on how to do this.

You mean "include" (link) statically to send the exe to someone or just to be able to run it? The runtime dll libraries are redistributable,  you can provide the with your exe. To be able to run in cmd, you have to run the configuration script provided by oneAPI.

I need to send the exe plus the dll (or some combination of those) to someone that does  not have the ability to run them inside VS.

To run your program in the command line, you should just run the configuration script provided by Intel. Check your documentation, like https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/programming-guide/2024-2/use-the-setvars-script-with-windows.html and other materials provided with your compiler. Try to link statically. I do not use Visual Studio or Windows, but it should be possible to set your project to link MKL statically. You may still need to distribute the redistributable runtime libraries with your exe.

I updated my post. I am not experienced enough to do this outside of VS. I just need to instruct the linker to somehow produce an exe, or an exe plus other files, that I can send to someone that just wants to execute the .exe, somehow.

Linking of MKL is decribed in the documentation, see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/get-started-guide/2024-0/overview.html#GUID-743B93DD-EF64-40E1-A597-C156522DB4AC and https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-guide-windows/2025-0/linking-your-application-with-onemkl.html There is the MKL Link advisor, to link statically, select Static for Select dynamic or static linking:

Anyway, have you at least tried, if your exe runs in your command line after executing the configuration script described in the first link I gave you? (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/programming-guide/2024-2/use-the-setvars-script-with-windows.html)

IN VS, under Libraries, change to /libs:static, check the pictures at https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/Static-linking-Intel-libraries-together-with-MSVC-static-link/td-p/1407373

Thanks to Vladimir's comments, here is the answer:

... in addition to using Math Kernel Library Sequential /Qmkl:sequential,... for Runtime library, you have to use /libs:static

@Echeban has the correct answer
I tested it out and run depends.exe to check dll dependencies after compilation.

Not MKL specific code, but you see on the bottom with /libs:static no dependencies on the Intel runtime libraries exists, unlike with the first case which uses /libs:dll
